# Swift: Picking two random, but unique, elements from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I would like to initialise an array as follows:

```
func initRoundsArray(playersArray: [String]) -> [String] {

    let rounds: [String] = [
        "ROUND 1: First player: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!)), Second player: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!))",
        "ROUND 2: First player: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!)), Second player: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!))",
        "ROUND 3: First player: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!)), Second player: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!))"
    ]

    return rounds
}
```

With the following code in my view controller:

```
let playersArrayInput: [String] = ["Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 5", "Player 6", "Player 7", "Player 8", "Player 9"]
var arrayOfRounds: [String]?

// Called like so in viewDidLoad:
arrayOfRounds = initRoundsArray(playersArray: playersArrayInput)
```

However I am struggling to figure out how to pick 2 random and unique elements for each round. For example, `arrayOfRounds[0]` may currently be `"ROUND 1: First player: Player 6, Second player: Player 6"`.

As `initRoundsArray` is only called once (`arrayOfRounds` is later mutated), I don't think it's appropriate to just shuffle the array and pick the first 2 elements, as in that case each round would be with the same 2 players.

I am not sure how to achieve this (or if it is even possible). Ideally all that is necessary is when picking two players for round 1, for example, it is checked that they are different to each other.

Comment: shuffle your array and then pick elements

Comment: @dahiya_boy I've discussed that approach in the question itself, penultimate paragraph.

Comment: you need to shuffle once not for every round

Comment: @dahiya_boy There may be a different number of players each time, the array provided in the question is just an example. If I were to shuffle as you suggest, how could I then continue to prevent duplicates?

Comment: @chumps52 Your question is a bit confusing. So a single round must contain 2 different players. But then you want unique pairs through as many rounds as possible. And players may change during execution. Is that what you are trying to do? Like a server starts and people start logging in and logging out so you want to keep making pairs of players for each round any you would like that pairs don't duplicate?

Comment: @MaticOblak I do apologise for the confusion. I've answered my own question now which may help clarify things, but essentially I wanted to generate a pair of players for each round where the two players were not the same. The `playersArray` would not change once the game had started. The code I provided initially had the potential to return, for example, `"ROUND 1: First player: Player 6, Second player: Player 6"`, where the first and second player in round 1 were both player 6, and thus would not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

You basically need to generate n random elements from an array, which you can do with this algorithm:

```
func pick<T>(_ n: Int, from array: [T]) -> [T] {
    var copy = array // make a copy so we can make changes
    var result = [T]()
    for _ in 0..<n {
        let randomElementIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<copy.count) // generate random index
        let randomElement = copy[randomElementIndex]
        copy.remove(at: randomElementIndex) // remove the generated element
        result.append(randomElement) // add it to the result
    }
    return result
}
```

To generate the players for 3 rounds, call this with `n=6`.

Comment: That `Int.random(in: 0..<n)` doesn't look correct since you are depleting items from `copy`. Assume it had 2 items and `n` is 2. The first element is correct but the second has 50% chance to roll index `1` but the only valid index left is 0 since `copy` now has only 1 item left in it.

Comment: @Kamran oops! Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a second array and instead of copy the value to the new array, pop the element to the new array so the second items that you will pop will be another one for sure.

Ex.

```
func initRoundsArray(playersArray: [String]) -> [String] {

    var playersArrayCoppy = playersArray
    let round1Item = playersArrayCoppy.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0...(playersArrayCoppy.count - 1)))
    let round2Item = playersArrayCoppy.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0...(playersArrayCoppy.count - 1)))
    let round3Item = playersArrayCoppy.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0...(playersArrayCoppy.count - 1)))

    let rounds: [String] = [
        "ROUND 1: First player: \(round1Item), Second player: \(round1Item)",
        "ROUND 2: First player: \(round2Item), Second player: \(round2Item)",
        "ROUND 3: First player: \(round3Item), Second player: \(round3Item)"
    ]
    return rounds
}
```

Of course you need to add some checks that you have items in the array if is not for sure that the array count is >= 3

**EDIT**
Based On the comments what you probably want is this function

```
func initRoundsArray(roundsNumber: Int, playersArray: [String]) -> [String] {
    var roundsArray:[String] = []
    for i in 1...roundsNumber {
        var playersArrayCoppy = playersArray
        let player1Item = playersArrayCoppy.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0...(playersArrayCoppy.count - 1)))
        let player2Item = playersArrayCoppy.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0...(playersArrayCoppy.count - 1)))

        let round: String = "ROUND \(i): First player: \(player1Item), Second player: \(player2Item)"
        roundsArray.append(round)
    }
    return roundsArray
}
```

and you call it with `initRoundsArray(roundsNumber: 3, playersArray: ["?","?",..."])`

Comment: I've just run that code and it guarantees duplicates: `["ROUND 1: First player: Player 9, Second player: Player 9", "ROUND 2: First player: Player 8, Second player: Player 8", "ROUND 3: First player: Player 7, Second player: Player 7"]`

Comment: no it Doesn't I just added round1Item to First player and SecondPlayer! Butt round1Item is always different from round2Item and round3Item I didn't understand that you want different per player, I thought you wanted per round. If you want different per player you need to call the function per round and use only 2 items

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like the following:

```
func extractRandomElementsFromArray<Generic>(_ array: [Generic], numberOfElements: Int) -> [Generic]? {
    guard array.count >= numberOfElements else { return nil }

    var toDeplete = array
    var toReturn = [Generic]()

    while toReturn.count < numberOfElements {
        toReturn.append(toDeplete.remove(at: Int.random(in: 0..<toDeplete.count)))
    }

    return toReturn
}
```

This should work on any array for any number of elements. Basically we are removing random elements from one array and fill them into another array until the second array has enough elements.

In your case this could be used as:

```
let playersArrayInput: [String] = ["Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 5", "Player 6", "Player 7", "Player 8", "Player 9"]

let pairArray = extractRandomElementsFromArray(playersArrayInput, numberOfElements: 2)!
let player1 = pairArray[0]
let player2 = pairArray[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using the following code (`<ACTION>` is just a placeholder):

```
func initRoundsArray(playersArray: [String]) -> [String] {

    let round1Players = twoRandomPlayers(playersArray: playersArray)
    let round2Players = twoRandomPlayers(playersArray: playersArray)

    let rounds: [String] = [
        "ROUND 1: \(round1players[0]), do <ACTION> to \(round1players[1])",
        "ROUND 2: \(round2players[0]), do <ACTION> to \(round2players[1])",
        "ROUND 3: \(String(playersArray.randomElement()!)), do <ACTION>"
    ]

    return rounds
}

func twoRandomPlayers(playersArray: [String]) -> [String] {
    let shuffledPlayersArray = playersArray.shuffled()

    return Array(shuffledPlayersArray.prefix(2))
}
```

I will call a separate function each time which returns an array with 2 randomly picked (and unique) players from the `playersArray`, and use that in the rounds that require 2 players.

I understand this may not be the best way of doing this, but in my final implementation it's likely that the vast majority of rounds will only involve one player, and thus `.randomElement()` is suitable.

I apologise if the wording in the original question was confusing, but I hope this clarifies things, and thank you very much to everyone for their suggestions/answers :)

Comment: Why does `ROUND 3` have only one player in it?

Comment: @ielyamani I mentioned this in the answer briefly, but in the actual implementation some rounds will only involve one player having to do something. The original question didn't mention this as I knew how to implement that already - the question I had was getting 2 non-duplicates in one string/round.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's suppose that `playersArrayInput` doesn't have any duplicates.

```
let playersArrayInput: [String] = ["Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4", "Player 5", "Player 6", "Player 7", "Player 8", "Player 9"]
```

An efficient implementation consists of shuffling only the indices :

```
func initRoundsArray(playersArray: [String]) -> [String] {

    var shuffledIndices = playersArray.indices.shuffled()
    let count = playersArray.count - 1
    var rounds = [String]()
    var i = 0

    while i <= count {
        let round = String(rounds.count + 1)
        if i <= count - 1 {
            switch Bool.random() {
            case true:
                rounds.append("ROUND " +
                    round +
                    ": " +
                    playersArray[shuffledIndices[i]] +
                    ", do <ACTION>")
                i += 1
            default:
                rounds.append("ROUND " +
                    round +
                    ": " +
                    playersArray[shuffledIndices[i]] +
                    ", do <ACTION> to " +
                    playersArray[shuffledIndices[i + 1]])
                i += 2
            }
        } else {
            rounds.append("ROUND " +
                round +
                ": " +
                playersArray[shuffledIndices[count]] +
                ", do <ACTION>")
            break
        }
    }

    return rounds
}
```

And we could print the result of the call this way :

```
initRoundsArray(playersArray: playersArrayInput).forEach { print($0) }
```

yielding for example :

```
ROUND 1: Player 7, do <ACTION> to Player 1
ROUND 2: Player 8, do <ACTION>
ROUND 3: Player 5, do <ACTION>
ROUND 4: Player 9, do <ACTION> to Player 2
ROUND 5: Player 3, do <ACTION> to Player 6
ROUND 6: Player 4, do <ACTION>
```